# Woocommerce fixed cart discount code. Discount appear as a reduction on the product and not on the cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hope your doing well today!

Well I'm facing something and I don't know if it's editable or if I can do something about it.

Basically on a WordPress site with some product and reduction code with the Woocommerce core.
They (the client who mandate the site) always use the fix reduction on the cart but in the order tab of woocommerce when we check an order the discount appea on the product(s) for exemple if I have 3 product in my cart and a fix discount: 50.

Everything is fine for the customer they have the reduction but in the backoffice if I check the order page and the recap the reduction apply on the cart and not split between product as show on the image.

Basicely what they asking me is how to apply only in the order/invoice/etc the reduction on the cart and not displying it to the product(s)

[image]

I hope i'm clear with my question if u need more information don't hesitate.
Thx everyone !

Comment: That seems like product discount. Check how this discount is applied. If its set to discount product will be recorded as product discount.

Comment: the setting of the cupon/discount is set to "fixed cart discount" so it should only apply on the cart total or not deduct from the product. But maybe i'm wrong and that's not how woocommerce use his discount system

Comment: I understand what u are refering. I just did some tests. So i think there is a reason to do it split among the products over just place it as total discount. Not sure. I need to look more into it.

Comment: I also do some test and with plugin to like this one: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-discount-rules/ .

But change nothing on the result but even with the cart adjustement at the end the deduction is apply on the product(s)